# How can paging a query be *slower*?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I'm timing the execution time of both a query, and the same query, paged.

```
foreach (var x in productSource.OrderBy(p => p.AdminDisplayName)
       .Where(p => allIds.Any(val => val == p.SiteProductId))) ;

foreach (var x in productSource.OrderBy(p => p.AdminDisplayName)
       .Where(p => allIds.Any(val => val == p.SiteProductId)).Skip(20).Take(20)) ;
```

Somehow, the first query is taking 0.5 seconds, and the second is taking three times that long.  How is that possible?  Unfortunately `allIds` is fairly complex, so the SQL generated is quite long.  I'm using Linq-to-SQL, which is why I used `Any` instead of `Contains`, since the latter causes an error for complex queries like this.

**EDIT**

It looks like the paged query runs faster (in absolute times) when the returned result set is larger.  When the base query returns 6,000 rows (before paging) the paged version runs at 1.7 seconds.  When the base query returns 200 rows (before paging) the paged version runs at 1.7 seconds.  This seems crazy to me.

**EDIT 2**

I was asked to supply query execution plans.  I've looked through both of them, and they appear to be identical, except for the very beginning.  Here are the parts that actually differ.

NOT PAGED
[image]

PAGED 
[image]

**END EDIT**

```
SELECT [t0].[SiteProductId], [t0].[SiteId], [t0].[SiteDivisionId], [t0].[ProductDisplayId], [t0].[ItemId], [t0].[SiteProductTypeId], [t0].[PrimaryParentSiteCategoryId], [t0].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId], [t0].[PrimaryChildSiteProductId], [t0].[UsesMasterPrice], [t0].[ListPrice], [t0].[SalePrice], [t0].[ShowWasIsPricing], [t0].[ArrivalDate], [t0].[SiteUrlKey], [t0].[IsDisplayedOnIndexPages], [t0].[HasDetailPage], [t0].[IsPersonalizable], [t0].[RequiresPersonalization], [t0].[ShowPersonalizationInline], [t0].[PzTemplateId], [t0].[AdminDisplayName], [t0].[DetailPageHeading], [t0].[SiteLabelForIndex], [t0].[SiteLabelForDetail], [t0].[UsesVariantAttributes], [t0].[VariantSelectionPrompt], [t0].[VariantSelectionOptionLabel], [t0].[VariantSortOrder], [t0].[VariantSelectionImageAssignmentId], [t0].[IndexImageAssignmentId], [t0].[DetailImageAssignmentId], [t0].[SiteProductDescription], [t0].[SiteTargetSearchTerms], [t0].[SiteWebPageTitle], [t0].[SiteWebPageKeywords], [t0].[SiteWebPageDescription], [t0].[ItemStatusId], [t0].[UsesMasterInventory], [t0].[CurrentInventory], [t0].[RestockDate], [t0].[IsBackorderable], [t0].[IsPreorderable], [t0].[OutOfStockLevel], [t0].[CreatedBy], [t0].[CreatedDT], [t0].[ModifiedBy], [t0].[ModifiedDT], [t0].[UsesPixamiPreview], [t0].[ShowsDynamicPreview], [t0].[IsNewProduct], [t0].[IsExclusiveProduct], [t0].[IsInternetOnlyProduct], [t0].[IsCustomerFavorite], [t0].[StartDate], [t0].[EndDate], [t0].[InternalKeywords], [t0].[ProductAlert], [t0].[AdditionalProductInfo], [t0].[UsesPixamiPz], [t0].[IsFreeGift], [t2].[test], [t2].[ItemId] AS [ItemId2], [t2].[ItemSku], [t2].[ErpItemId], [t2].[SupplierSku], [t2].[VendorSku], [t2].[UPC], [t2].[SerialNumber], [t2].[DisplayName], [t2].[IsPersonalizable] AS [IsPersonalizable2], [t2].[RequiresPersonalization] AS [RequiresPersonalization2], [t2].[ListPrice] AS [ListPrice2], [t2].[ItemTypeId], [t2].[ItemTypeCode], [t2].[DisplayIndividuallyOnSite], [t2].[ItemStatusId] AS [ItemStatusId2], [t2].[ItemStatusCode], [t2].[ParentItemId], [t2].[VariantTemplateCode], [t2].[PzFormatCode], [t2].[OmsPzTemplateId], [t2].[Height], [t2].[Width], [t2].[Depth], [t2].[Weight], [t2].[CurrentInventory] AS [CurrentInventory2], [t2].[RestockDate] AS [RestockDate2], [t2].[IsTaxable], [t2].[PostHand], [t2].[LastSyncDate], [t2].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy2], [t2].[CreatedDT] AS [CreatedDT2], [t2].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy2], [t2].[ModifiedDT] AS [ModifiedDT2]
FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS [test], [t1].[ItemId], [t1].[ItemSku], [t1].[ErpItemId], [t1].[SupplierSku], [t1].[VendorSku], [t1].[UPC], [t1].[SerialNumber], [t1].[DisplayName], [t1].[IsPersonalizable], [t1].[RequiresPersonalization], [t1].[ListPrice], [t1].[ItemTypeId], [t1].[ItemTypeCode], [t1].[DisplayIndividuallyOnSite], [t1].[ItemStatusId], [t1].[ItemStatusCode], [t1].[ParentItemId], [t1].[VariantTemplateCode], [t1].[PzFormatCode], [t1].[OmsPzTemplateId], [t1].[Height], [t1].[Width], [t1].[Depth], [t1].[Weight], [t1].[CurrentInventory], [t1].[RestockDate], [t1].[IsTaxable], [t1].[PostHand], [t1].[LastSyncDate], [t1].[CreatedBy], [t1].[CreatedDT], [t1].[ModifiedBy], [t1].[ModifiedDT]
    FROM [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2] ON [t2].[ItemId] = [t0].[ItemId]
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t43].[SiteProductId]
        FROM (
            SELECT [t28].[SiteProductId]
            FROM (
                SELECT [t13].[SiteProductId]
                FROM (
                    SELECT [t3].[SiteProductId]
                    FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t3]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t4] ON [t4].[ItemId] = [t3].[ItemId]
                    WHERE ([t3].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p0) AND (([t3].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p1) OR ([t4].[ItemSku] LIKE @p2)) AND ([t3].[SiteId] = @p3)
                    UNION
                    SELECT [t12].[SiteProductId]
                    FROM (
                        SELECT [t5].[SiteProductId]
                        FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t5]
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t6] ON [t6].[ItemId] = [t5].[ItemId]
                        WHERE ([t5].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND (EXISTS(
                            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                            FROM (
                                SELECT [t7].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] AS [value], [t7].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId], [t7].[SiteProductTypeId], [t7].[AdminDisplayName], [t8].[ItemSku], [t7].[SiteId]
                                FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t7]
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t8] ON [t8].[ItemId] = [t7].[ItemId]
                                ) AS [t9]
                            WHERE ([t9].[value] = ([t5].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId])) AND ([t9].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t9].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p4) AND (([t9].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p5) OR ([t9].[ItemSku] LIKE @p6)) AND ([t9].[SiteId] = @p7)
                            ))
                        UNION
                        SELECT [t10].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] AS [value]
                        FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t10]
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t11] ON [t11].[ItemId] = [t10].[ItemId]
                        WHERE ([t10].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t10].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p8) AND (([t10].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p9) OR ([t11].[ItemSku] LIKE @p10)) AND ([t10].[SiteId] = @p11)
                        ) AS [t12]
                    ) AS [t13]
                UNION
                SELECT [t14].[ParentSiteProductId]
                FROM [dbo].[SiteProductAssociation] AS [t14]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[SiteProductAssociationType] AS [t15] ON [t15].[SiteProductAssociationTypeId] = [t14].[SiteProductAssociationTypeId]
                WHERE (EXISTS(
                    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                    FROM (
                        SELECT [t26].[SiteProductId]
                        FROM (
                            SELECT [t16].[SiteProductId]
                            FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t16]
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t17] ON [t17].[ItemId] = [t16].[ItemId]
                            WHERE ([t16].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p12) AND (([t16].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p13) OR ([t17].[ItemSku] LIKE @p14)) AND ([t16].[SiteId] = @p15)
                            UNION
                            SELECT [t25].[SiteProductId]
                            FROM (
                                SELECT [t18].[SiteProductId]
                                FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t18]
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t19] ON [t19].[ItemId] = [t18].[ItemId]
                                WHERE ([t18].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND (EXISTS(
                                    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                                    FROM (
                                        SELECT [t20].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] AS [value], [t20].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId], [t20].[SiteProductTypeId], [t20].[AdminDisplayName], [t21].[ItemSku], [t20].[SiteId]
                                        FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t20]
                                        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t21] ON [t21].[ItemId] = [t20].[ItemId]
                                        ) AS [t22]
                                    WHERE ([t22].[value] = ([t18].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId])) AND ([t22].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t22].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p16) AND (([t22].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p17) OR ([t22].[ItemSku] LIKE @p18)) AND ([t22].[SiteId] = @p19)
                                    ))
                                UNION
                                SELECT [t23].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] AS [value]
                                FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t23]
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t24] ON [t24].[ItemId] = [t23].[ItemId]
                                WHERE ([t23].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t23].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p20) AND (([t23].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p21) OR ([t24].[ItemSku] LIKE @p22)) AND ([t23].[SiteId] = @p23)
                                ) AS [t25]
                            ) AS [t26]
                        ) AS [t27]
                    WHERE [t27].[SiteProductId] = [t14].[ChildSiteProductId]
                    )) AND ([t14].[SiteProductAssociationTypeId] = @p24)
                ) AS [t28]
            UNION
            SELECT [t29].[ChildSiteProductId]
            FROM [dbo].[SiteProductAssociation] AS [t29]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[SiteProductAssociationType] AS [t30] ON [t30].[SiteProductAssociationTypeId] = [t29].[SiteProductAssociationTypeId]
            WHERE (EXISTS(
                SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                FROM (
                    SELECT [t41].[SiteProductId]
                    FROM (
                        SELECT [t31].[SiteProductId]
                        FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t31]
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t32] ON [t32].[ItemId] = [t31].[ItemId]
                        WHERE ([t31].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p25) AND (([t31].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p26) OR ([t32].[ItemSku] LIKE @p27)) AND ([t31].[SiteId] = @p28)
                        UNION
                        SELECT [t40].[SiteProductId]
                        FROM (
                            SELECT [t33].[SiteProductId]
                            FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t33]
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t34] ON [t34].[ItemId] = [t33].[ItemId]
                            WHERE ([t33].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND (EXISTS(
                                SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                                FROM (
                                    SELECT [t35].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] AS [value], [t35].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId], [t35].[SiteProductTypeId], [t35].[AdminDisplayName], [t36].[ItemSku], [t35].[SiteId]
                                    FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t35]
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t36] ON [t36].[ItemId] = [t35].[ItemId]
                                    ) AS [t37]
                                WHERE ([t37].[value] = ([t33].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId])) AND ([t37].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t37].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p29) AND (([t37].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p30) OR ([t37].[ItemSku] LIKE @p31)) AND ([t37].[SiteId] = @p32)
                                ))
                            UNION
                            SELECT [t38].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] AS [value]
                            FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t38]
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t39] ON [t39].[ItemId] = [t38].[ItemId]
                            WHERE ([t38].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t38].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p33) AND (([t38].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p34) OR ([t39].[ItemSku] LIKE @p35)) AND ([t38].[SiteId] = @p36)
                            ) AS [t40]
                        ) AS [t41]
                    ) AS [t42]
                WHERE [t42].[SiteProductId] = [t29].[ParentSiteProductId]
                )) AND ([t29].[SiteProductAssociationTypeId] = @p37)
            ) AS [t43]
        ) AS [t44]
    WHERE [t44].[SiteProductId] = [t0].[SiteProductId]
    )
ORDER BY [t0].[AdminDisplayName]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1

SELECT [t45].[SiteProductId], [t45].[SiteId], [t45].[SiteDivisionId], [t45].[ProductDisplayId], [t45].[ItemId], [t45].[SiteProductTypeId], [t45].[PrimaryParentSiteCategoryId], [t45].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId], [t45].[PrimaryChildSiteProductId], [t45].[UsesMasterPrice], [t45].[ListPrice], [t45].[SalePrice], [t45].[ShowWasIsPricing], [t45].[ArrivalDate], [t45].[SiteUrlKey], [t45].[IsDisplayedOnIndexPages], [t45].[HasDetailPage], [t45].[IsPersonalizable], [t45].[RequiresPersonalization], [t45].[ShowPersonalizationInline], [t45].[PzTemplateId], [t45].[AdminDisplayName], [t45].[DetailPageHeading], [t45].[SiteLabelForIndex], [t45].[SiteLabelForDetail], [t45].[UsesVariantAttributes], [t45].[VariantSelectionPrompt], [t45].[VariantSelectionOptionLabel], [t45].[VariantSortOrder], [t45].[VariantSelectionImageAssignmentId], [t45].[IndexImageAssignmentId], [t45].[DetailImageAssignmentId], [t45].[SiteProductDescription], [t45].[SiteTargetSearchTerms], [t45].[SiteWebPageTitle], [t45].[SiteWebPageKeywords], [t45].[SiteWebPageDescription], [t45].[ItemStatusId], [t45].[UsesMasterInventory], [t45].[CurrentInventory], [t45].[RestockDate], [t45].[IsBackorderable], [t45].[IsPreorderable], [t45].[OutOfStockLevel], [t45].[CreatedBy], [t45].[CreatedDT], [t45].[ModifiedBy], [t45].[ModifiedDT], [t45].[UsesPixamiPreview], [t45].[ShowsDynamicPreview], [t45].[IsNewProduct], [t45].[IsExclusiveProduct], [t45].[IsInternetOnlyProduct], [t45].[IsCustomerFavorite], [t45].[StartDate], [t45].[EndDate], [t45].[InternalKeywords], [t45].[ProductAlert], [t45].[AdditionalProductInfo], [t45].[UsesPixamiPz], [t45].[IsFreeGift], [t45].[test], [t45].[ItemId2], [t45].[ItemSku], [t45].[ErpItemId], [t45].[SupplierSku], [t45].[VendorSku], [t45].[UPC], [t45].[SerialNumber], [t45].[DisplayName], [t45].[IsPersonalizable2], [t45].[RequiresPersonalization2], [t45].[ListPrice2], [t45].[ItemTypeId], [t45].[ItemTypeCode], [t45].[DisplayIndividuallyOnSite], [t45].[ItemStatusId2], [t45].[ItemStatusCode], [t45].[ParentItemId], [t45].[VariantTemplateCode], [t45].[PzFormatCode], [t45].[OmsPzTemplateId], [t45].[Height], [t45].[Width], [t45].[Depth], [t45].[Weight], [t45].[CurrentInventory2], [t45].[RestockDate2], [t45].[IsTaxable], [t45].[PostHand], [t45].[LastSyncDate], [t45].[CreatedBy2], [t45].[CreatedDT2], [t45].[ModifiedBy2], [t45].[ModifiedDT2]
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t0].[AdminDisplayName]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t0].[SiteProductId], [t0].[SiteId], [t0].[SiteDivisionId], [t0].[ProductDisplayId], [t0].[ItemId], [t0].[SiteProductTypeId], [t0].[PrimaryParentSiteCategoryId], [t0].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId], [t0].[PrimaryChildSiteProductId], [t0].[UsesMasterPrice], [t0].[ListPrice], [t0].[SalePrice], [t0].[ShowWasIsPricing], [t0].[ArrivalDate], [t0].[SiteUrlKey], [t0].[IsDisplayedOnIndexPages], [t0].[HasDetailPage], [t0].[IsPersonalizable], [t0].[RequiresPersonalization], [t0].[ShowPersonalizationInline], [t0].[PzTemplateId], [t0].[AdminDisplayName], [t0].[DetailPageHeading], [t0].[SiteLabelForIndex], [t0].[SiteLabelForDetail], [t0].[UsesVariantAttributes], [t0].[VariantSelectionPrompt], [t0].[VariantSelectionOptionLabel], [t0].[VariantSortOrder], [t0].[VariantSelectionImageAssignmentId], [t0].[IndexImageAssignmentId], [t0].[DetailImageAssignmentId], [t0].[SiteProductDescription], [t0].[SiteTargetSearchTerms], [t0].[SiteWebPageTitle], [t0].[SiteWebPageKeywords], [t0].[SiteWebPageDescription], [t0].[ItemStatusId], [t0].[UsesMasterInventory], [t0].[CurrentInventory], [t0].[RestockDate], [t0].[IsBackorderable], [t0].[IsPreorderable], [t0].[OutOfStockLevel], [t0].[CreatedBy], [t0].[CreatedDT], [t0].[ModifiedBy], [t0].[ModifiedDT], [t0].[UsesPixamiPreview], [t0].[ShowsDynamicPreview], [t0].[IsNewProduct], [t0].[IsExclusiveProduct], [t0].[IsInternetOnlyProduct], [t0].[IsCustomerFavorite], [t0].[StartDate], [t0].[EndDate], [t0].[InternalKeywords], [t0].[ProductAlert], [t0].[AdditionalProductInfo], [t0].[UsesPixamiPz], [t0].[IsFreeGift], [t2].[test], [t2].[ItemId] AS [ItemId2], [t2].[ItemSku], [t2].[ErpItemId], [t2].[SupplierSku], [t2].[VendorSku], [t2].[UPC], [t2].[SerialNumber], [t2].[DisplayName], [t2].[IsPersonalizable] AS [IsPersonalizable2], [t2].[RequiresPersonalization] AS [RequiresPersonalization2], [t2].[ListPrice] AS [ListPrice2], [t2].[ItemTypeId], [t2].[ItemTypeCode], [t2].[DisplayIndividuallyOnSite], [t2].[ItemStatusId] AS [ItemStatusId2], [t2].[ItemStatusCode], [t2].[ParentItemId], [t2].[VariantTemplateCode], [t2].[PzFormatCode], [t2].[OmsPzTemplateId], [t2].[Height], [t2].[Width], [t2].[Depth], [t2].[Weight], [t2].[CurrentInventory] AS [CurrentInventory2], [t2].[RestockDate] AS [RestockDate2], [t2].[IsTaxable], [t2].[PostHand], [t2].[LastSyncDate], [t2].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy2], [t2].[CreatedDT] AS [CreatedDT2], [t2].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy2], [t2].[ModifiedDT] AS [ModifiedDT2]
    FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t0]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 1 AS [test], [t1].[ItemId], [t1].[ItemSku], [t1].[ErpItemId], [t1].[SupplierSku], [t1].[VendorSku], [t1].[UPC], [t1].[SerialNumber], [t1].[DisplayName], [t1].[IsPersonalizable], [t1].[RequiresPersonalization], [t1].[ListPrice], [t1].[ItemTypeId], [t1].[ItemTypeCode], [t1].[DisplayIndividuallyOnSite], [t1].[ItemStatusId], [t1].[ItemStatusCode], [t1].[ParentItemId], [t1].[VariantTemplateCode], [t1].[PzFormatCode], [t1].[OmsPzTemplateId], [t1].[Height], [t1].[Width], [t1].[Depth], [t1].[Weight], [t1].[CurrentInventory], [t1].[RestockDate], [t1].[IsTaxable], [t1].[PostHand], [t1].[LastSyncDate], [t1].[CreatedBy], [t1].[CreatedDT], [t1].[ModifiedBy], [t1].[ModifiedDT]
        FROM [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t1]
        ) AS [t2] ON [t2].[ItemId] = [t0].[ItemId]
    WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM (
            SELECT [t43].[SiteProductId]
            FROM (
                SELECT [t28].[SiteProductId]
                FROM (
                    SELECT [t13].[SiteProductId]
                    FROM (
                        SELECT [t3].[SiteProductId]
                        FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t3]
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t4] ON [t4].[ItemId] = [t3].[ItemId]
                        WHERE ([t3].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p0) AND (([t3].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p1) OR ([t4].[ItemSku] LIKE @p2)) AND ([t3].[SiteId] = @p3)
                        UNION
                        SELECT [t12].[SiteProductId]
                        FROM (
                            SELECT [t5].[SiteProductId]
                            FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t5]
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t6] ON [t6].[ItemId] = [t5].[ItemId]
                            WHERE ([t5].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND (EXISTS(
                                SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                                FROM (
                                    SELECT [t7].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] AS [value], [t7].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId], [t7].[SiteProductTypeId], [t7].[AdminDisplayName], [t8].[ItemSku], [t7].[SiteId]
                                    FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t7]
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t8] ON [t8].[ItemId] = [t7].[ItemId]
                                    ) AS [t9]
                                WHERE ([t9].[value] = ([t5].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId])) AND ([t9].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t9].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p4) AND (([t9].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p5) OR ([t9].[ItemSku] LIKE @p6)) AND ([t9].[SiteId] = @p7)
                                ))
                            UNION
                            SELECT [t10].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] AS [value]
                            FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t10]
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t11] ON [t11].[ItemId] = [t10].[ItemId]
                            WHERE ([t10].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t10].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p8) AND (([t10].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p9) OR ([t11].[ItemSku] LIKE @p10)) AND ([t10].[SiteId] = @p11)
                            ) AS [t12]
                        ) AS [t13]
                    UNION
                    SELECT [t14].[ParentSiteProductId]
                    FROM [dbo].[SiteProductAssociation] AS [t14]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[SiteProductAssociationType] AS [t15] ON [t15].[SiteProductAssociationTypeId] = [t14].[SiteProductAssociationTypeId]
                    WHERE (EXISTS(
                        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                        FROM (
                            SELECT [t26].[SiteProductId]
                            FROM (
                                SELECT [t16].[SiteProductId]
                                FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t16]
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t17] ON [t17].[ItemId] = [t16].[ItemId]
                                WHERE ([t16].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p12) AND (([t16].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p13) OR ([t17].[ItemSku] LIKE @p14)) AND ([t16].[SiteId] = @p15)
                                UNION
                                SELECT [t25].[SiteProductId]
                                FROM (
                                    SELECT [t18].[SiteProductId]
                                    FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t18]
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t19] ON [t19].[ItemId] = [t18].[ItemId]
                                    WHERE ([t18].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND (EXISTS(
                                        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                                        FROM (
                                            SELECT [t20].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] AS [value], [t20].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId], [t20].[SiteProductTypeId], [t20].[AdminDisplayName], [t21].[ItemSku], [t20].[SiteId]
                                            FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t20]
                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t21] ON [t21].[ItemId] = [t20].[ItemId]
                                            ) AS [t22]
                                        WHERE ([t22].[value] = ([t18].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId])) AND ([t22].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t22].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p16) AND (([t22].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p17) OR ([t22].[ItemSku] LIKE @p18)) AND ([t22].[SiteId] = @p19)
                                        ))
                                    UNION
                                    SELECT [t23].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] AS [value]
                                    FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t23]
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t24] ON [t24].[ItemId] = [t23].[ItemId]
                                    WHERE ([t23].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t23].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p20) AND (([t23].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p21) OR ([t24].[ItemSku] LIKE @p22)) AND ([t23].[SiteId] = @p23)
                                    ) AS [t25]
                                ) AS [t26]
                            ) AS [t27]
                        WHERE [t27].[SiteProductId] = [t14].[ChildSiteProductId]
                        )) AND ([t14].[SiteProductAssociationTypeId] = @p24)
                    ) AS [t28]
                UNION
                SELECT [t29].[ChildSiteProductId]
                FROM [dbo].[SiteProductAssociation] AS [t29]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[SiteProductAssociationType] AS [t30] ON [t30].[SiteProductAssociationTypeId] = [t29].[SiteProductAssociationTypeId]
                WHERE (EXISTS(
                    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                    FROM (
                        SELECT [t41].[SiteProductId]
                        FROM (
                            SELECT [t31].[SiteProductId]
                            FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t31]
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t32] ON [t32].[ItemId] = [t31].[ItemId]
                            WHERE ([t31].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p25) AND (([t31].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p26) OR ([t32].[ItemSku] LIKE @p27)) AND ([t31].[SiteId] = @p28)
                            UNION
                            SELECT [t40].[SiteProductId]
                            FROM (
                                SELECT [t33].[SiteProductId]
                                FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t33]
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t34] ON [t34].[ItemId] = [t33].[ItemId]
                                WHERE ([t33].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND (EXISTS(
                                    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                                    FROM (
                                        SELECT [t35].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] AS [value], [t35].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId], [t35].[SiteProductTypeId], [t35].[AdminDisplayName], [t36].[ItemSku], [t35].[SiteId]
                                        FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t35]
                                        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t36] ON [t36].[ItemId] = [t35].[ItemId]
                                        ) AS [t37]
                                    WHERE ([t37].[value] = ([t33].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId])) AND ([t37].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t37].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p29) AND (([t37].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p30) OR ([t37].[ItemSku] LIKE @p31)) AND ([t37].[SiteId] = @p32)
                                    ))
                                UNION
                                SELECT [t38].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] AS [value]
                                FROM [dbo].[SiteProduct] AS [t38]
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ItemMaster] AS [t39] ON [t39].[ItemId] = [t38].[ItemId]
                                WHERE ([t38].[PrimaryParentSiteProductId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t38].[SiteProductTypeId] <> @p33) AND (([t38].[AdminDisplayName] LIKE @p34) OR ([t39].[ItemSku] LIKE @p35)) AND ([t38].[SiteId] = @p36)
                                ) AS [t40]
                            ) AS [t41]
                        ) AS [t42]
                    WHERE [t42].[SiteProductId] = [t29].[ParentSiteProductId]
                    )) AND ([t29].[SiteProductAssociationTypeId] = @p37)
                ) AS [t43]
            ) AS [t44]
        WHERE [t44].[SiteProductId] = [t0].[SiteProductId]
        )
    ) AS [t45]
WHERE [t45].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p38 + 1 AND @p38 + @p39
ORDER BY [t45].[ROW_NUMBER]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: Is the SQL you have shown us for the first LINQ query, for the second one or for both? I.e. are there any differences in generated SQL?

Comment: @Branko -- both.  The only difference I can see is that the second includes a ROW_NUMBER OVER function used for paging.

Comment: Could you please copy-paste both versions of the SQL (with and without ROW_NUMBER) into SQL Server Management Studio and see if there is any difference in execution plan? You don't need to provide actual parameter values for generating execution plans, so you should be able to paste the SQL text without any modifications.

Comment: Have you tried 'objectifying' `allIds`. IOW Add a ToList() somewhere? Alternatively a dictionary mapping could help.

Comment: @AdamRackis One more question - when you say that query "runs" and takes some time, do you mean "returns the first row" or do you actually fetch all the returned rows before measuring time?

Comment: I iterate over the result set, and measure the time from beginning to end.  I start the timer before the for loop starts, and stop it after it finishes.

Comment: @AdamRackis I'm sorry but I cant see why the difference in execution plans would account for the observed behavior. Did you try running the **same** query twice in succession - do you observe a time difference? Maybe you are paying some unexpected query preparation cost?

Comment: @leppie Actually `AsEnumerable` would be more efficient - it does not need to allocate the actual space for the list, nor to fetch all the rows in advance.

Comment: @Branko - good thought, but no.  I can it three times, and they never differed by more than 0.1 seconds.  Like I said, it seems when there are a huge number of results, the paging works beautifully.  When there are only a few results, materializing the AllIDs collection and using that in the query is actually faster.  Go figure.  I'll just put a check in, and do the one thing or the other based on how big AllIDs is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the "select top X from" syntax, the generated SQL uses the ROW_NUMBER() function, and than selects based on it.
It is of course a very heavy operation, as the function is called for every row, and only then is the "WHERE" clause evaluated, while the "SELECT TOP X" syntax just stops execution after X rows are selected.

I can't tell you if it's possible to fix this in LINQ2SQL, but I am quite sure Entity Framework uses "SELECT TOP X FROM" syntax, although I can't tell you for sure.

I don't know how complicated is it for you to move to Entity Framework, but I can tell you for sure it will make your life easier in many ways, and will perform much better, provided you use the .NET 4.0 Entity Framework and not .NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: do you have any idea why the paged version, with ROW_NUMBER() would actually run very quickly when my search parameters yield large results?  When my query returns 6,000 rows, the paged version runs just as fast as the unpaged version.  But when the search only returns 100 items, the paged version slows way down.

Comment: Can't tell you for sure. Will need your database to run the query on and see the execution plan. What I can tell you for sure, is that with "SELECT TOP X" the paged version would run faster than ordinary.